# Filtering rows withing Admin using a Queryset - Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-queryset

I'm trying to find a way to filter down rows of objects within Django Admin, using a queryset.

```
e.g. Person.objects.filter(Q(name='John')|Q(surname='Doe'))
```

I'm finding quite complicated to figure out.

---

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean you want to do something like a search, or you want to display generally only selected objects in the changelist?

Comment: @lazerscience Yes, something like search, but using a queryset like the one above. My intention is to search for all person rows that match the name or the surname.

Comment: Don't understand...Can you tell me more about this issue?

Comment: This is not what you are looking for: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.search_fields

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to accomplish this by overriding the queryset() method on your modeladmin instance. See http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/options.py?rev=15347#L196

```
# untested code
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(MyModelAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        return qs.filter(Q(name='John') | Q(surname='Doe'))
```

This would only affect results for the model registered with that ModelAdmin, but you could probably subclass it as a starting point for other ModelAdmin classes in order to stay DRY.

I'm not saying this is a good idea.